# How can I add autocompletion to WebStorm for Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, appcelerator-titanium

I'm wanting to run with WebStorm rather than Appcelerator Studio, and these docs will (apparently) enable autocomplete inside of Jetbrains, which will make it a viable option.

However I can no longer find the JSON files that I've heard can be used for this. They used to live at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/data/

Any advice/options?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it**.

Comment: I'm not asking for a random resource.  I'm asking for an exact resource that Appcelerator used to provide and may have moved, or another way to do the same thing.

Comment: That's still off-topic on SO; asking us to find _any_ resource is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an actual git repo: https://github.com/DeSater/jsca2js

This is the newest 5.0.0.GA auto completion file: https://github.com/DeSater/jsca2js/blob/master/titanium-js/titanium-mobile-5.0.0.js